How can I display Docker container logs in real-time in a Next.js 15 project using Dockerode?
I'm working on an admin dashboard in Next.js 15 where I want to display Docker container logs in real-time. I’m using Dockerode to interact with Docker, and I'm able to get a stream of logs using the method. However, the logs don’t seem to display in the component when I expect them to.logs
Here is the relevant part of my code:
Backend function for fetching logs:
//@/Docker/Container/LogContainer
'use server';
import Docker from '@/Docker/server';

interface LogContainerConfig {
    id: string; // Container ID
}

async function LogContainer(config: LogContainerConfig) {
    try {
        const container = await Docker.getContainer(config.id);
        
        const logStream = await container.logs({
            follow: true,
            stdout: true,
            stderr: true
        });

        let logData = '';

        logStream.on('data', (chunk: Buffer) => {
            logData += chunk.toString();
            console.log(chunk.toString()); // Logs to console
        });

        logStream.on('end', () => {
            console.log(`Logs for container ${config.id} ended.`);
        });

        return logData;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching container logs:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}

export { LogContainer };

client
'use client';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Dockerode from 'dockerode';
import { LogContainer } from '@/Docker/Container/LogContainer';

const AdminPage = () => {
    const [logs, setLogs] = useState<string>('');
    const [logContainerId, setLogContainerId] = useState<string | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchLogs = async (containerId: string) => {
            setLogs(''); // Clear previous logs
            setLogContainerId(containerId);

            try {
                const data = await LogContainer({ id: containerId });
                setLogs(data.toString());
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching container logs:', error);
            }
        };

        fetchLogs('container-id');
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Logs for Container {logContainerId}</h2>
            <pre>{logs || 'No logs available'}</pre>
        </div>
    );
};

export default AdminPage;

